# AUCTeX/LaTeX - ERROR: Undefined control sequence. documentclass

Tags: latex, auctex

I am using AUCTeX with the following configuration.

```
(require 'tex)
(setq TeX-auto-save t)
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
(setq-default TeX-master "main")
(setq latex-run-command "pdflatex")
```

Trying to build my document with `C-c C-a` gives me the error

```
ERROR: Undefined control sequence.

--- TeX said ---
l.1 \documentclass{IEEEtran}
```

My `main.tex` file looks like this:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\renewcommand\_{\textunderscore\allowbreak}

\begin{document}

\title{foo bar}
\author{foo}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
  Blockchain
\end{IEEEkeywords}


% Einleitung
\import{./}{intro.tex}


\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{references}



\end{document}
```

Using `pdflatex` on the terminal is just working fine.

Why does my `emacs` say different? I though internally is just a `pdflatex` call and... violá.

Comment: Which version of AUCTeX do you have (`C-h v AUCTeX-version RET`) and how did you install it? I suggest you install the latest version via ELPA, drop the lines `(require 'tex)` and `(setq latex-run-command "pdflatex")` in your `.emacs` and try it again. You can also check the output buffer with `C-c C-l` to see how TeX was invoked.

Comment: The message would imply that you tried to process the contents of the file with pure TeX, not LaTeX (`documentclass` is a LaTeX macro). I don't think you are using `pdflatex` from Emacs when you compile your document. Probably it just calls to something that knows how to process just TeX.

Comment: thanks this `C-c C-l` really did the thing. `pdflatex` was not correctly included into my `path` in `emacs`.